# Creating Google+ Account without Gmail address

Tags: gmail, google, google-plus, yahoo

Google allows us to use many of its services without having a Gmail account. But when I visit Google+ and click on the "Sign Up" button, it asks to select a new username and create a new password.

Is it possible to create a new Google+ Account without a Gmail address, but with, say, a Yahoo address?

Comment: Checkout this url : http://socialmedia101.artizondigital.com/2012/01/ricks-tips-sign-up-for-a-google-account-without-signing-up-for-gmail-or-google-plus/

Comment: I am asking about creating Google Plus account and not all the other Google Services.

Comment: To sign up for Google+ you need a Google account. You don't need to _use_ all of those other Google services, but you can't divorce the account from them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can create a Google account with your Yahoo email address—or any other email address, for that matter—if you follow this link: https://accounts.google.com/NewAccount.

Just to make things clearer because your question mixes some issues that might lead to confusion:

If you want to sign up for Google Plus with a Yahoo email address and you already have a Google account under that address, you cannot sign up for Google Plus separately. It will all be linked in your Google account.

If you use only Google services that do not require a Google account—such as Search, Maps, Translate—and you have not created one yet, you will be forced to create a Google account upon signing up for Google Plus. After all, it is linked to your identity and therefore you need to create an account (I know I am stating the obvious, but one should never assume any prior knowledge).